# Reverse of an Amount and counting

Tags: phrases, terminology

We use this phrase to announce some voting-like results:

> 1 million and counting

This is for something which we expect to increase in the future, but what phrase can we use for something that will decrease in the future, like time,

For example, for the phrase *50 days are left*,

> 50 days and reverse counting

Is this the phrase to use, or is there any other term or phrase that can be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could still use *counting* if it's clear which direction you are actually counting in.

> How long do you have left to retirement?
>   Down to fifty days and counting.

Answer (score 7):

You can use *and counting* if the direction in which you count is clear from your context.

Otherwise, you can use **counting down**.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `decreasing`

> 50 days and decreasing

de·crease  (dĭ-krēs′)
To grow or cause to grow gradually less or smaller, as in number, amount, or intensity.

Answer (score 1):

The number of remaining days is 50 and falling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `decending`

[Decending](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/descend): "move or fall downwards."

Comment: Not really appropriate, even if you'd spelt it correctly.

Comment: What @Tim said (but I have to say it shows real [chutspah](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chutzpah) to misspell a link to a dictionary definition! :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps...

50 days and declining?

Answer (score 0):

For passage of time in particular, you can say "*and ticking*" using a clock as a metaphor.

> 30 seconds to detonation and ticking!

Another phrasing for counting down is [*T-minus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown), attributed to NASA.

> T-minus 50 days and counting.

Answer (score -1):

I think, Countdown can be used.

Comment: How could it be used? I'd like to see you try to incorporate that into a sentence.